# Change Image src with document.getElementByClassName and ngif directive

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am trying to change icon images on load by using `document.getElementByClassName`. These icons are repeated several times. The code is using `ngIf` to show a different icon based on conditions performed by the user.

```
<img class="viewlist_button_icon ng-scope" ng-if="fun.__inViewlist" src="source_file/image.png">
<!-- end ngIf: fun.__inViewlist -->
<!-- ngIf: !fun.__inViewlist -->
```

I have successfully changed the icons using the following:

```
var elems = document.getElementsByClassName("viewlist_button_icon ng-scope");
for (var i = 0; i < elems.length; i+= 1) {
    elems[i].src = "https://new_image.png";
}
```

I cannot figure out how to change both icons controlled by the `ng-if`

icon #1: `ng-if="fun.__inViewlist"`

icon #2: `ng-if="!fun.__inViewlist"`

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

if you use angular.js (not angular 2 and above) , place the image address in $scope and then change the $scope to change the image like this :

```
$scope.myimg = '/img/icon1.jpg' ;
```

do not forget to use ng-src in image tags :

```
<img ng-src="{{myimg}}">
```

ng-scr is important , src will not work

```
<img src="{{myVar}}"> [this will not wok]
```